# Docusign with VBA - code 401

Tags: docusignapi

i am trying to get past the simple log template in with DocuSign. Can anyone  kindly tell me what is missing in the VBA code. Is there quotes or anything I need to make this work. I added some quotes around my email address. I have a sandbox account and my developer key, but i get a 401 error whether i send execute the "GET" or not. i did take this code from another tread in stackoverflow but i dont know what was in the excel cells to make this code work.

```
Public Sub APICallTest()
Dim httpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim httpResult As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

' defined request and result variables
Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP60
Set httpResult = New DOMDocument60

'open login information url https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2
 httpRequest.Open "GET", "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information.XML", False

httpRequest.setRequestHeader "X-DocuSign-Authentication:  <DocuSignCredentials><Username>MyUserName</Username><Password>" + Chr(34) + "my@myemail.com" + Chr(34)</Password><IntegratorKey>myintegratorkey</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>Accept: application/xml Content-Type: application/xml", "text"

' send login information request
httpRequest.send
Debug.Print httpRequest.Status, "A"
Debug.Print httpRequest.statusText, "B"
Debug.Print httpRequest.responseText, "C"

Exit Sub
```

Comment: This is what i get back when the code runs:

Comment: 401          A
Unauthorized  B
{
  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}             C

Comment: Can you see what's being sent to DocuSign? it sounds like your header isn't setting properly (make sure you have the correct username/password/integrator key.

Comment: is there a web site or tool  that can display the string being sent?

Comment: fiddler2 can decrypt the traffic that you're sending out from your localhost box as a raw request (with headers)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what the problem is- your Integrator Key is either not present in the request or is invalid (i.e. incorrect).  I see your VB code that shows you apparently including the key in the header, however since you haven't posted the raw request you're sending out my guess is that your code is not working properly and the key or the header is not being set properly.

Try doing this:

1. Login to your demo account, go into your preference, and enable the Request Logging feature. (more on how to do that below)
2. Run your code.
3. Go back into your account preferences and retrieve the log that would have been created.
4. Inspect the log and make sure your Integrator Key and X-DocuSign-Authentication header are present and correct.

For a more complete guide on how to enable request logging in your account see here:

https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Or here if you're using the Classic DocuSIgn UI:

https://support.docusign.com/articles/API-Request-Logging

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is caused because you are trying to set more than one header in the httpRequest.setRequestHeader statement.

I recommend splitting them up to seperate statements

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication","<DocuSignCredentials><Username>MyUserName</Username><Password>" + Chr(34) + "my@myemail.com" + Chr(34)+"</Password><IntegratorKey>myintegratorkey</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>")
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/xml");
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766589(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this proves helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Ron, I am glad my suggestion was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It works now!! this is what it ended up looking in VBA. How does someone know to put "application/xml" on the end of the Header definition?

```
Public Sub APICallTest()
Dim httpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim httpResult As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
'defined request and result variables
Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP60
Set httpResult = New DOMDocument60
'open login information url https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2
httpRequest.Open "GET", "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information"

httpRequest.setRequestHeader "X-DocuSign-Authentication", "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>my@email.com</Username><Password>mypassword</Password><IntegratorKey>mykey</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>"
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
httpRequest.send
Debug.Print httpRequest.Status, "A"
Debug.Print httpRequest.statusText, "B"
Debug.Print httpRequest.responseText, "C"
Set httpRequest = Nothing
Set httpResult = Nothing
Exit Sub
```